# is kill delete statment in state updating roleback entire data?

Tags: mysql, database, pycharm

i try to revert the statement `DELETE from table_name where id > 10000;` . i am using MySQL 5.6 server , i perform the statement from pycahrm database client and then hit stop in the client about 2 seconds after, but i saw in `show full processlist` that the query was still in state updating after several minutes so i delete it with kill  , is the database is reverted and no data was actually deleted ? i can see id's 10001,10002 ... but can i bee 100 percent sure that all data was not deleted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you should be alright as long as you see id's 10001, 10002,..

Delete should always start from beginning.
I tried on my test_db and ran:
`DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id > 1 LIMIT 1`

and saw that it starts from 2 and not last id